# Xcode iOS app hanging on launch screen "semaphore_wait_trap()"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, permissions, alert, freeze

Excuse me but I'm a total Noob, not a programmer. I based a photo editing app on a template and customised it heavily with help from Google searches, tutorials etc.

Using Xcode 7.3.1, iOS 9.3, newer Photosframework and only objective C.
Ive got the app to a point that Im happy with it, except that I noticed on first launch, the app hangs (debug reports semaphore_wait_trap().

The app can't get to next step "request to access photos" alert pop up in iOS 9.3, and only way to get to it is to hit the home button, then see the grant access alert, then switch back to app. Then quit the app, reload it and then it runs fine overtime after that. This is of course not an ideal user experience.

I see if I pause on debug mode its hanging on: "semaphore_wait_trap()"

Ive googled and searched for days and can't find a solution to get the permissions alert popup to show on top of my app window.

Its beyond me. Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

See screen shot of the launch image that remains on top of the alert pop up.

If you press the "Home" button, the alert to grant access to photos appears.

The app delegate:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (locationNotification) {
    // Sets icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
//  END Local Notification ==========================


return true;

}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

// Resets icon's badge number to zero
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

}
```

Here is a snippet of the main View controller (hope its not to long, not sure where the problem lies)

HomeVC.m:

```
#import "HomeVC.h"
#import "Configs.h"
#import "AAPLGridViewCell2.h"
#import "NSIndexSet+Convenience.h"
#import "UICollectionView+Convenience.h"
#import "AAPLRootListViewController.h"
#import "Configs.h"
#import "ImageEditorTheme.h"
#import "ImageEditorTheme+Private.h"

@import PhotosUI;
@import UIKit;


@interface HomeVC()
<
PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver,
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,
UICollectionViewDataSource,
UICollectionViewDelegate
>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sectionFetchResults;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *sectionLocalizedTitles;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PHCachingImageManager *imageManager;
@property CGRect previousPreheatRect;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout;

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGSize lastTargetSize;


@end


@implementation HomeVC

{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *_indicatorView;
}

static NSString * const AllPhotosReuseIdentifier = @"AllPhotosCell";
static NSString * const CollectionCellReuseIdentifier = @"CollectionCell";

static NSString * const CellReuseIdentifier = @"Cell";
static CGSize AssetGridThumbnailSize;


- (void)awakeFromNib {

    self.imageManager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
    [self resetCachedAssets];

    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] registerChangeObserver:self];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] unregisterChangeObserver:self];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    _logoImage.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
    [self loadPhotos];

    [_libraryOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handle_data) name:@"reload_data" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideMenu) name:@"hide_menu" object:nil];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Begin caching assets in and around collection view's visible rect.
    [self updateCachedAssets];
}

-(void)handle_data {
    //[self.collectionView2 layoutIfNeeded];
    //[self resetCachedAssets];

    [self.collectionView2 reloadData];
    [self updateCachedAssets];
    NSLog(@"did it work?");
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    NSInteger section = [self.collectionView2 numberOfSections] - 1;
    NSInteger item = [self.collectionView2 numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
    [self.collectionView2 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:(UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop) animated:NO];
    //[self loadPhotos];
}

-(void) loadPhotos {

    PHFetchOptions *allPhotosOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]];

    PHFetchResult *allPhotos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:allPhotosOptions];


    if (self.assetsFetchResults == nil) {
        self.assetsFetchResults = allPhotos;
    }
}



#pragma mark - PHPhotoLibraryChangeObserver

- (void)photoLibraryDidChange:(PHChange *)changeInstance {
    // Check if there are changes to the assets we are showing.
    PHFetchResultChangeDetails *collectionChanges = [changeInstance changeDetailsForFetchResult:self.assetsFetchResults];
    if (collectionChanges == nil) {
        return;
    }

    /*
     Change notifications may be made on a background queue. Re-dispatch to the
     main queue before acting on the change as we'll be updating the UI.
     */
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Get the new fetch result.
        self.assetsFetchResults = [collectionChanges fetchResultAfterChanges];

        UICollectionView *collectionView = self.collectionView;

        if (![collectionChanges hasIncrementalChanges] || [collectionChanges hasMoves]) {
            // Reload the collection view if the incremental diffs are not available
            [collectionView reloadData];

        } else {
            /*
             Tell the collection view to animate insertions and deletions if we
             have incremental diffs.
             */
            [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                NSIndexSet *removedIndexes = [collectionChanges removedIndexes];
                if ([removedIndexes count] > 0) {
                    [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[removedIndexes aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                }

                NSIndexSet *insertedIndexes = [collectionChanges insertedIndexes];
                if ([insertedIndexes count] > 0) {
                    [collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:[insertedIndexes aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                }

                NSIndexSet *changedIndexes = [collectionChanges changedIndexes];
                if ([changedIndexes count] > 0) {
                    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[changedIndexes aapl_indexPathsFromIndexesWithSection:0]];
                }
            } completion:NULL];
        }

        [self resetCachedAssets];
    });
}



#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.assetsFetchResults.count;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {

    CGFloat colum = 3.0, spacing = 0.0;
    CGFloat value = floorf((CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) - (colum - 1) * spacing) / colum);

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout  = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize                     = CGSizeMake(value, value);
    layout.sectionInset                 = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing      = spacing;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing           = spacing;


    return CGSizeMake(value, value);
    //return self.collectionView.frame.size;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PHAsset *asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];

    // Dequeue an AAPLGridViewCell.
    AAPLGridViewCell2 *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.representedAssetIdentifier = asset.localIdentifier;


    // Request an image for the asset from the PHCachingImageManager.
    [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                 targetSize:CGSizeMake(130, 130)
                                contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                    options:nil
                              resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                  // Set the cell's thumbnail image if it's still showing the same asset.
                                  if ([cell.representedAssetIdentifier isEqualToString:asset.localIdentifier]) {
                                      cell.thumbnailImage = result;
                                  }
                              }];
    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(-0, self.collectionView.contentSize.height - self.collectionView.bounds.size.height + self.collectionView.contentInset.bottom);
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];;
        return cell;

}

- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Prepare the options to pass when fetching the live photo.
    PHAsset *asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];
    PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
    options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
    options.networkAccessAllowed = NO;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _indicatorView = [ImageEditorTheme indicatorView];
        _indicatorView.center = self.containerView.center;
        [self.containerView addSubview:_indicatorView];
        [_indicatorView startAnimating];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    PreviewVC *prevVC = (PreviewVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PreviewVC"];

    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {


            // Show the UIImageView and use it to display the requested image.
            passedImage = result;

            prevVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            [self presentViewController:prevVC animated:true completion:nil];
        [_indicatorView stopAnimating];
        }];
    });
}


#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    // Update cached assets for the new visible area.
    [self updateCachedAssets];
}
```

Comment: Nobody have any suggestions?

Comment: you need to provide either some screenshots or code , so that ur main problem can be understood properly..

Comment: or provide ur app delegate class code ...

Comment: i guess from app delegate u r moving to Home view controller...u need to set root view controller as self.window.rootViewController = HomeViewController;

Comment: @jayantrawat, not sure what you mean, or how to implement this?

Comment: // use this code to navigate from ur app delegate class to home view controller //                                                                                              self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
[self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];  self.viewController=[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;                 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: @jayantrawat, I'm not winning. Ive updated my post with some debug info where its hanging. Where do I put this code? app delegate or home viewcontroller?

Comment: //use below code in app delegate did finish with launching method to move to 1st controller in ur app// UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 ViewController *rootViewController1 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Mainiphone6"];
  navC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController1];
  self.window.rootViewController = navC;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: @jayantrawat, Xcode complains: Use of undeclared identifier "navC" and I assume "Viewcontroller is supposed to be my HomeVC view controller instead?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. It was as simple as removing the call to "[self resetCachedAssets];" in "awakeFromNib"

Works great now.